# PHP - Loop and merge array based on same Key

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($total_month_hours_result as $key => $data){ print_r($data); } //outputs below array

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 176
            [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180
            [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
        )

)
```

Again looping the array

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val ){print_r($val);} // outputs below array


Array
(
    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 176
    [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
)

Array
(
    [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180
    [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
)
```

Tried below code

```
$hours_array = Array();
foreach ($project_months as $month) {

    foreach ($total_month_hours_result as $key => $data){

        if (!empty($data)){

            foreach ($data as $key => $val ){

                if ($val['MONTH_YEAR'] == $month ){

                  $hours_array[$val['MONTH_YEAR']][$month]['SITE_STATUS'] = $val['SITE_STATUS'];
                  $hours_array[$val['MONTH_YEAR']][$month]['OFFSHORE_HOURS'] = $val['OFFSHORE_HOURS'];
                  $hours_array[$val['MONTH_YEAR']][$month]['ONSITE_HOURS'] = $val['ONSITE_HOURS'];
                  $hours_array[$val['MONTH_YEAR']][$month]['TOTAL_HOURS'] = $val['ONSITE_HOURS'] + $val['OFFSHORE_HOURS'];

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [APR-2015] => Array
        (
            [APR-2015] => Array
                (
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
                    [TOTAL_HOURS] => 356
                    [ONSITE_HOURS] => 180
                    [OFFSHORE_HOURS] => 176
                )

        )       
)
```

Based on key `month_year` how do I merge two arrays resulting into below output

```
Array
(
    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 176
    [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180
    [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
)
```

**EDIT**

What I am actually trying to achieve is to show Onsite, Offshore and Total Hours in table form like below

It does display the hours correctly for the first APR-2015 but not for JUN-15

```
Name of Engineer    Site  MAR-15  Site    APR-15  Site     JUN-15
User 1                            Onsite   120    Offshore  170              
User 2                            Offshore 140    Offshore  180

Total Hours                                260                                          350
Total Onsite                               120                                          0
Total Offshore                             140                                          350
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  decode(pr.siteid,   397,   'Onsite',   398,   'Offshore') AS
site_status,
  SUM(tm.user_hours) AS
actual_hours,
  tm.month_year
FROM project_resource pr
INNER JOIN monthly_table tm ON tm.resource_id = pr.employeeid
 AND tm.project_id = pr.projectid
INNER JOIN resource_table rd ON rd.employeeid = pr.employeeid
INNER JOIN expband_view exbvw ON exbvw.employeeid = pr.employeeid
INNER JOIN mastercode_table mc ON mc.codeid = rd.primaryskill
WHERE tm.project_id = 741
 AND tm.month_year = 'APR-2015' --months will be passed dynamically
GROUP BY pr.siteid,tm.month_year
ORDER BY SITE_STATUS DESC
```

**SQL Result**

```
SITE_STATUS  ACTUAL_HOURS   MONTH_YEAR
Onsite        307           APR-2015
Offshore      352           APR-2015
```

Comment: Such a resulting array is not achievable as you can not duplicate array keys (e.g. `ACTUAL_HOURS`).

Comment: You can't. The duplicate array keys will clash, at best you'll get the 2nd set of data.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary SNAP! Great minds, yatta yatta yatta

Comment: you could place two arrays inside one though. For example array1( with key based on month_year) would have the onsite info as key 1, and offsite info as key 2.

Comment: @CodeGodie no need to use numeric keys, just use `Onsite` and `Offshore`.

Comment: @KevinNagurski that would work as well.

Comment: @KevinNagurski, updated my question to what is required. Also how could  I make use of two arrays for onsite and offshore values

Comment: I would focus more on your sql query rather than on iterating through these results. What is your current sql query to obtain these results?

Comment: @CodeGodie, pls see updated question with SQL and its output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ideal output isn't really achievable, but you can use this:

```
$results = array();

foreach ($total_month_hours_result as $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $data) {
        $results[$data['MONTH_YEAR']][$data['SITE_STATUS']] = $data['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
    }
}
```

To produce this:

```
Array
(
    [APR-15] => Array
    (
        [Offshore] => 176,
        [Onsite]   => 180
    )
    // ...
)
```

Comment: $data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 176
            [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180
            [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
        )

). So we again need to loop the data

Comment: So what is `$total_month_hours_result`? The example in the question shows that `$data` will be `Array([SITE_STATUS] => Onsite, [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180, [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015)`

Comment: print_r($total_month_hours_result);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 176
                    [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
                    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180
                    [MONTH_YEAR] => APR-2015
                )

        )

)

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I didn't spot that extra layer of array. I've updated my answer to reflect that.